# Use both "-" and "+" for command style in boost program options

Tags: boost

```
po::command_line_style::style_t style = po::command_line_style::style_t(
            po::command_line_style::unix_style |
            po::command_line_style::case_insensitive |
            po::command_line_style::allow_long_disguise );

    po::store(po::parse_command_line(argc, argv, commandOptions,style), vm);
    po::notify(vm);
```

The command line that I am trying to parse is of the form

-abc abc_value +xyz xyz_value

I would like to configure the boost program options to use both "-" and "+". I read the help and it states that "**The allowed character
for short options is also configurable**." But I could not figure out how to do it.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you have not read the whole thing, or you're just taking that sentence out of context. On that same line it also says "... and "short", which start with either "-" or "/". " [The same page](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/command_line_style/style_t.html) also lists and explains all the options.

Answer (score 1):

The configurability just refers to the following style flags:

- allow_dash_for_short

  Allow "-" in short options.
- allow_slash_for_short

  Allow "/" in short options.

You cannot freely choose a short-option leader character.